# Make customizer panel or section button

Tags: php, theme-customizer

I have created a section in the theme customizer named Next Step, then when that is clicked on I made a button that says Edit Pages which links to the pages section in WordPress. There are two things wrong with this. First, I want the Next Step section to actually be a button (button button-primary) and go straight into the edit pages section instead of clicking twice. Second, is that I get a 'wp.customize is undefined' in Firefox Dev tools on all other pages in admin and messes up some of the functionality of those pages. I can't seem to figure out how to do this and any help is appreciated.

```
function prefix_customizer_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'section_id', array(
        'priority' => 300,
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'theme_supports' => '',
        'title' => __( 'Next Step', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => '',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'button_id', array(
        'type' => 'button',
        'settings' => array(),  
        'priority' => 10,
        'section' => 'section_id',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'value' => __( 'Edit Pages', 'textdomain' ),
            'class' => 'button button-primary',
    ),
) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'prefix_customizer_register' );
```

Here is the script to make the button link to the edit pages section...

```
wp.customize.control( 'button_id', function( control ) {
    control.container.find( '.button' ).on( 'click', function() {
        window.open('edit.php?post_type=page', '_top');
    } );
} );
```

**Updated** - using action for script resolved errors:

```
function custom_customize_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-customize', plugins_url() . '/next-step-button/custom.customize.js', array( 'jquery', 'customize-controls' ), false, true );
}

add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_customize_enqueue' );
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `button` instead of an `input[type=button]`? Also, share the code you're using to enqueue the JS. You should add `'customize-controls'` as its script dependency and only enqueue it at the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: input[type=button] would be ok also. I am inserting the script with a plugin that inserts code into the admin interface. I actually used that action and that worked for the js so that issue is resolved, thanks!